# Shading intensities of all points

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want the intensities of all the points in the 3d scatter plot, where the light source is at the center of the 3d scatter plot.
Also how to add the lightsource at the center?
The code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
df=pd.read_csv('wr.csv')
col_name='pH'
xmin=df.index.min()
xmax=df.index.max()
ymin=df[col_name].min()
ymax=df[col_name].max()
zval=np.mean(np.square(df[col_name]))
x = df.index
y = df[col_name].values
z = np.square(df[col_name].values)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df.index, df[col_name], np.square(df[col_name]), s=0.5,color='black')
ax.scatter(np.mean(df.index),np.mean(df[col_name]),zval,color='orange',s=300)
ax.plot_surface([[xmin, xmax], [xmin, xmax]], [[ymin, ymin], [ymax, ymax]], np.array([[zval, zval], [zval, zval]]), alpha=0.5,color='blue')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
 
ls = LightSource()
shading_array = ls.shade(z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('cool'))
print(shading_array)
```

I am getting an error with this code despite giving the correct number of arguments.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 20
     17 ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
     19 ls = LightSource()
---> 20 shading_array = ls.shade(z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('cool'))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:2428, in LightSource.shade(self, data, cmap, norm, blend_mode, vmin, vmax, vert_exag, dx, dy, fraction, **kwargs)
   2425     norm = Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
   2427 rgb0 = cmap(norm(data))
-> 2428 rgb1 = self.shade_rgb(rgb0, elevation=data, blend_mode=blend_mode,
   2429                       vert_exag=vert_exag, dx=dx, dy=dy,
   2430                       fraction=fraction, **kwargs)
   2431 # Don't overwrite the alpha channel, if present.
   2432 rgb0[..., :3] = rgb1[..., :3]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:2483, in LightSource.shade_rgb(self, rgb, elevation, fraction, blend_mode, vert_exag, dx, dy, **kwargs)
   2437 """
   2438 Use this light source to adjust the colors of the *rgb* input array to
   2439 give the impression of a shaded relief map with the given *elevation*.
   (...)
   2480     An (m, n, 3) array of floats ranging between 0-1.
   2481 """
   2482 # Calculate the "hillshade" intensity.
-> 2483 intensity = self.hillshade(elevation, vert_exag, dx, dy, fraction)
   2484 intensity = intensity[..., np.newaxis]
   2486 # Blend the hillshade and rgb data using the specified mode

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:2302, in LightSource.hillshade(self, elevation, vert_exag, dx, dy, fraction)
   2299 dy = -dy
   2301 # compute the normal vectors from the partial derivatives
-> 2302 e_dy, e_dx = np.gradient(vert_exag * elevation, dy, dx)
   2304 # .view is to keep subclasses
   2305 normal = np.empty(elevation.shape + (3,)).view(type(elevation))

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in gradient(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:1184, in gradient(f, axis, edge_order, *varargs)
   1182         dx[i] = diffx
   1183 else:
-> 1184     raise TypeError("invalid number of arguments")
   1186 if edge_order > 2:
   1187     raise ValueError("'edge_order' greater than 2 not supported")

TypeError: invalid number of arguments
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gv5O4evmtTRibf33ak3TnLQmgUUA9tw7/view?usp=drive_link)

- relevant data column

```
pH
3.51
3.2
3.26
3.16
3.51
3.51
3.3
3.39
3.36
3.35
3.28
3.35
3.58
3.26
3.16
3.17
3.3
3.11
3.38
3.04
3.39
3.52
3.17
3.17
3.43
3.34
3.28
3.17
3.47
3.38
3.35
3.46
3.17
3.45
3.38
3.4
3.42
3.23
3.5
3.33
3.33
3.26
3.21
3.3
3.48
3.9
3.25
3.25
3.34
3.32
3.15
3.4
3.39
3.2
3.17
3.34
3.04
3.26
3.43
3.41
3.44
3.21
3.38
3.39
3.41
3.41
3.42
3.44
3.28
3.34
3.32
3.32
3.31
3.31
3.28
3.54
3.54
3.52
3.38
3.16
3.41
3.13
3.36
3.16
3.44
3.41
2.93
3.39
3.14
3.48
3.23
2.93
2.93
3.39
3.75
3.85
3.45
3.25
3.39
3.3
3.4
3.31
3.3
3.29
3.33
3.29
3.08
3.46
3.37
3.21
3.19
3.15
3.15
3.32
3.19
3.07
3.39
3.37
3.21
3.34
3.3
3.21
3.49
3.44
3.39
3.16
3.53
3.54
3.42
3.42
3.24
3.63
3.63
3.4
3.22
3.19
3.23
3.48
3.33
3.32
3.19
3.23
3.68
3.34
3.68
3.17
3.54
3.11
3.42
3.53
3.33
2.74
3.35
3.35
3.42
3.42
3.42
3.42
3.48
3.59
3.2
3.17
3.33
3.37
3.37
3.19
3.34
3.37
3.47
3.0
3.36
3.29
3.29
3.42
3.33
3.35
3.33
3.58
3.48
3.19
3.19
3.12
3.44
3.54
3.52
3.26
3.34
3.39
3.2
3.2
3.23
3.57
3.28
3.28
3.28
3.25
3.46
3.11
3.57
3.51
3.22
3.04
3.36
3.34
3.34
3.2
3.2
3.29
3.22
3.31
3.3
3.35
3.21
3.3
3.24
3.34
3.14
3.36
3.39
3.3
3.34
3.15
3.42
3.28
3.31
3.37
3.04
3.39
3.37
3.46
3.54
3.37
3.34
3.46
3.32
3.37
3.37
3.37
3.37
3.32
3.0
3.14
3.08
3.07
3.07
3.61
3.38
3.2
3.35
3.61
3.22
3.47
3.17
3.23
3.47
3.26
3.22
3.49
3.06
3.36
3.29
3.35
3.34
3.28
3.08
3.2
3.6
3.35
3.69
3.28
3.36
3.28
3.22
3.31
3.38
3.36
3.69
3.28
3.23
3.38
3.12
3.25
3.36
3.38
3.31
3.31
3.1
3.37
3.34
3.2
3.34
3.3
3.22
3.41
3.05
3.05
3.16
3.67
3.67
3.68
3.38
3.22
3.51
3.39
3.2
3.12
3.36
3.19
3.19
3.41
3.12
3.27
3.32
3.3
3.39
3.42
3.3
3.3
3.37
3.3
3.37
3.24
3.29
3.28
3.16
3.16
3.05
3.28
3.16
3.18
3.23
3.23
3.22
3.13
3.34
3.17
3.35
3.31
3.16
3.11
3.12
3.21
3.3
3.3
3.12
3.6
3.58
3.02
3.11
3.36
3.28
3.35
3.27
3.18
3.25
3.55
3.26
3.24
3.15
3.17
3.19
3.37
3.05
2.99
3.07
3.26
3.07
3.16
3.18
3.2
3.57
3.32
3.32
3.05
3.01
3.01
3.26
3.2
3.11
3.31
3.21
3.06
3.21
3.21
3.42
3.43
3.41
3.31
3.43
3.19
3.56
3.06
3.18
3.16
3.03
3.22
3.47
3.18
3.18
3.1
3.47
3.29
3.1
3.15
3.26
3.36
3.24
3.18
3.19
3.05
3.38
3.38
3.27
3.27
3.26
3.32
3.26
3.44
3.24
3.62
3.28
3.52
3.36
3.15
3.36
3.52
3.49
3.26
3.24
3.1
3.15
3.25
3.0
3.16
3.15
3.16
3.26
3.17
3.15
3.08
2.88
3.06
2.95
3.23
3.57
3.23
3.1
3.22
3.2
3.1
3.1
3.06
3.44
3.26
3.5
3.22
3.37
3.28
3.26
3.25
3.35
3.26
3.18
3.08
2.98
3.48
3.16
3.32
3.17
3.2
3.05
3.2
3.15
3.26
3.2
3.14
3.28
3.18
3.14
3.19
3.12
3.15
3.04
3.04
3.06
3.17
3.17
3.17
3.32
3.34
3.31
3.34
3.32
3.48
3.44
3.15
3.43
3.32
3.15
3.48
3.43
3.17
3.17
3.18
3.21
3.16
3.25
3.17
3.18
3.04
3.02
3.18
3.03
3.09
3.09
3.31
3.25
3.16
3.22
3.36
3.42
3.48
3.38
3.22
3.23
3.24
3.36
3.39
3.34
3.09
3.41
3.16
3.16
3.22
3.28
3.41
3.09
3.37
3.2
3.22
3.26
3.21
3.12
3.06
2.86
3.08
3.45
3.26
3.12
3.27
3.33
3.19
3.12
3.74
2.92
2.92
3.07
2.92
3.07
3.3
3.14
3.23
3.08
3.31
3.3
3.14
3.32
3.32
3.31
3.57
3.32
3.57
3.14
3.3
3.19
3.2
3.34
3.3
3.29
3.14
3.19
3.19
3.19
2.98
3.3
3.47
3.12
3.26
3.72
3.05
3.35
3.12
3.35
3.29
3.4
3.27
3.04
3.09
3.2
3.0
3.26
3.1
3.3
3.1
3.17
3.31
3.34
3.31
3.32
3.56
3.39
2.98
3.32
3.26
2.87
3.5
3.5
3.03
3.13
3.09
3.27
3.28
3.13
3.49
3.46
3.46
3.36
3.36
3.27
3.21
3.27
3.25
3.32
3.43
3.27
3.27
3.24
3.24
3.35
3.18
3.39
3.46
3.39
3.46
3.39
3.37
3.4
3.32
3.33
3.16
2.89
3.41
2.98
3.12
3.08
3.14
2.89
2.92
3.32
3.41
3.32
3.31
3.36
3.04
3.03
3.14
3.18
2.94
3.15
2.94
3.26
3.2
3.15
3.2
3.08
3.26
3.08
3.4
3.48
3.13
3.06
3.21
3.33
3.37
3.25
3.37
3.44
3.28
3.4
3.3
3.63
3.48
3.03
3.32
3.31
3.9
3.47
3.47
3.31
3.11
3.08
3.47
3.47
3.32
3.29
3.37
3.4
3.37
3.34
3.27
3.06
3.38
3.36
3.34
3.28
3.29
3.34
3.21
3.22
3.46
3.22
3.1
3.21
2.94
3.54
3.29
3.43
3.46
3.46
3.61
3.17
3.44
3.39
3.55
3.48
3.26
3.26
3.5
3.1
3.35
3.45
3.21
3.46
3.13
3.13
3.52
3.3
3.3
3.52
3.52
3.29
3.29
3.39
3.29
3.09
3.51
3.6
3.25
3.25
3.19
3.23
3.25
3.31
3.25
3.31
3.31
3.14
3.45
3.55
3.39
3.55
3.28
3.27
3.3
3.31
3.43
3.4
3.4
3.36
3.5
3.31
3.66
3.36
3.66
3.55
3.21
3.21
3.18
3.18
3.09
3.33
3.23
3.48
3.38
3.17
2.99
3.1
3.24
3.29
3.29
3.25
3.23
3.56
3.24
3.26
3.33
3.27
3.33
3.26
3.22
3.3
3.09
3.24
3.44
3.21
3.24
3.23
3.28
3.29
3.28
3.34
3.71
3.61
3.61
3.24
3.36
3.4
3.36
3.46
3.56
3.38
3.56
3.38
3.38
3.32
3.39
3.26
3.26
3.24
3.46
3.24
3.45
3.23
3.28
3.18
3.59
3.59
3.5
3.59
3.58
3.28
3.28
3.22
3.47
3.47
3.51
3.47
3.4
3.15
3.4
3.51
3.66
3.24
3.51
3.51
3.51
3.41
3.4
3.4
3.44
3.41
3.53
3.43
3.23
3.12
3.31
3.4
3.41
3.22
3.53
3.15
3.48
3.22
3.53
3.22
3.34
3.33
3.15
3.43
3.22
3.44
3.53
3.22
3.53
3.53
3.42
3.31
3.42
3.31
3.48
3.4
3.58
3.58
3.41
3.41
3.23
3.39
3.59
3.43
3.29
3.23
3.18
3.33
3.27
3.29
3.27
3.62
3.38
3.3
3.38
3.24
3.3
3.38
3.38
3.18
3.47
3.47
3.2
3.18
3.3
3.69
3.48
3.45
3.48
3.69
3.39
3.39
3.07
3.34
3.61
3.36
3.19
3.22
3.24
3.27
3.14
3.29
3.26
3.41
3.41
3.41
3.26
3.31
3.2
3.44
3.36
3.31
3.29
3.47
3.36
3.16
3.27
3.38
3.15
3.16
3.34
3.13
3.13
3.2
3.46
3.33
3.33
3.22
3.52
3.3
3.44
3.44
3.15
3.28
3.13
3.32
3.25
3.34
3.32
3.13
3.45
3.19
3.44
3.16
3.14
3.16
3.45
3.36
3.45
3.15
3.39
3.71
3.71
3.12
3.47
3.44
3.26
3.26
3.36
3.25
3.36
3.26
3.26
3.23
3.18
3.25
3.17
3.23
3.38
3.22
3.06
3.27
2.89
2.89
3.53
3.2
3.2
3.35
3.27
3.32
3.33
3.41
3.49
3.37
3.32
3.42
3.35
3.36
3.3
3.2
3.17
3.22
3.35
3.24
3.33
3.58
3.38
3.33
3.29
3.36
3.32
3.31
3.49
3.27
3.27
3.49
3.03
3.56
3.38
3.13
3.13
3.21
3.15
3.19
3.21
3.14
3.21
3.3
3.22
3.28
3.29
3.4
3.02
3.02
3.31
3.18
3.2
3.4
3.31
3.2
3.44
3.15
3.27
3.27
3.01
3.16
3.01
3.42
3.33
3.42
3.12
3.38
3.29
3.02
3.02
2.98
3.35
3.43
3.33
3.35
3.15
3.35
3.2
3.15
3.2
3.11
3.35
3.45
3.35
3.28
3.41
3.21
3.27
3.36
3.17
3.25
3.78
3.29
3.12
3.49
3.38
3.38
3.38
3.3
3.52
3.2
3.44
3.45
3.12
3.62
3.14
3.39
3.51
3.22
3.21
3.18
3.32
3.38
3.37
3.3
3.38
3.22
3.22
3.14
3.34
3.41
3.27
3.3
3.61
3.43
3.53
3.28
3.21
3.39
3.23
3.3
3.46
3.15
3.23
3.59
3.15
3.33
3.46
3.42
3.16
3.14
3.21
3.14
3.29
3.29
3.01
2.94
3.32
3.21
3.32
3.2
3.42
3.27
3.46
3.46
3.61
3.58
3.35
3.68
3.27
3.27
3.19
3.38
3.29
3.36
3.33
3.52
3.33
3.36
3.3
3.28
3.56
3.52
3.56
3.22
3.52
3.21
3.16
3.15
3.21
3.16
3.27
3.35
3.14
3.4
3.4
3.4
3.35
3.4
3.45
3.35
3.32
3.35
3.15
3.1
3.26
3.29
3.23
3.24
3.2
3.28
3.28
3.26
3.23
3.07
3.15
3.02
3.27
3.68
3.4
3.37
3.38
3.4
3.23
3.39
3.3
3.26
3.39
3.38
3.45
3.1
3.16
3.22
3.37
3.33
3.49
3.12
3.49
3.41
3.4
3.4
3.28
3.45
3.43
3.4
3.47
3.1
3.32
3.44
3.44
3.02
3.59
3.15
3.37
3.38
3.38
3.38
3.1
3.47
3.5
3.7
3.38
3.5
3.1
3.24
3.24
3.28
3.35
3.24
3.14
3.37
3.37
3.33
3.26
3.39
3.15
3.35
3.22
3.3
3.3
3.36
3.29
3.62
3.34
3.29
3.2
3.2
3.35
3.45
3.5
3.78
3.6
3.3
3.36
3.12
3.3
3.29
3.41
3.29
3.28
3.3
3.33
3.34
3.4
3.4
3.26
4.01
3.18
3.26
2.9
3.26
4.01
3.18
3.18
3.39
3.39
3.39
3.39
3.34
3.29
3.29
3.26
3.09
3.18
3.39
3.38
3.36
3.36
3.36
3.36
3.36
3.36
3.37
3.36
3.09
3.25
3.52
3.34
3.34
3.41
3.34
3.32
3.37
3.37
3.35
3.36
3.36
3.6
3.28
3.07
3.24
3.36
3.07
3.29
3.46
3.18
3.24
3.25
3.27
3.33
3.0
3.21
3.0
3.24
3.32
3.26
3.11
3.71
3.29
3.36
3.36
3.38
3.3
3.3
3.19
3.19
3.3
3.3
3.35
3.1
3.58
3.37
3.17
3.3
3.32
3.31
3.31
3.28
3.52
3.42
3.25
3.25
3.44
3.23
3.43
3.28
3.22
3.54
3.27
3.54
3.5
3.56
3.22
3.04
3.2
3.56
3.2
3.35
3.16
3.27
3.16
3.34
3.39
3.5
3.26
3.26
3.41
3.3
3.31
3.33
3.37
3.26
3.48
3.42
3.18
3.18
3.15
3.53
3.41
3.32
3.23
3.16
3.4
3.38
3.32
3.16
3.4
3.4
3.4
3.23
3.23
3.33
3.35
3.41
3.21
3.5
3.3
3.41
3.39
3.32
3.41
3.59
3.36
3.34
3.41
3.41
3.3
3.52
3.3
3.31
2.88
3.43
3.38
3.38
3.16
3.54
3.16
3.54
3.4
3.39
3.66
3.39
3.33
3.35
3.53
3.37
3.38
3.52
3.72
3.44
3.39
3.72
3.57
3.26
3.42
3.35
3.26
3.45
3.53
3.45
3.26
3.16
3.31
3.51
3.36
3.55
3.51
3.36
3.38
3.28
3.47
3.44
3.53
3.33
3.53
3.53
3.42
3.38
3.32
3.44
3.38
3.39
3.42
3.34
3.39
3.33
3.3
3.29
3.31
3.42
3.42
3.6
3.21
3.39
3.42
3.36
3.6
3.5
3.57
3.46
3.56
3.4
3.3
3.25
3.17
3.36
3.36
3.55
3.1
3.24
3.45
3.44
3.51
3.41
3.54
3.44
3.53
3.54
3.22
3.21
3.21
3.21
3.29
3.29
3.29
3.39
3.34
3.29
3.34
3.48
3.37
3.44
3.33
3.58
3.39
3.26
3.3
3.54
3.42
3.54
3.36
3.54
3.57
3.33
3.29
3.3
3.34
3.55
3.27
3.29
3.32
3.67
3.42
3.42
3.45
3.52
3.42
3.57
3.39
```

Comment: You should look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72302677/7758804) and the shape `data` and `cmap` relative to each other.

Comment: The answer you mentioned uses the `np.meshgrid` function, I am not sure if I can use that here.

Comment: You’re still not following the parameter instructions, data should be 2d

Comment: I tried reshaping the z variable using np.reshape(z,(-1,1)) but it gives the following error, `raise ValueError( ValueError: Shape of array too small to calculate a numerical gradient, at least (edge_order + 1) elements are required.` @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: You’ll have to see if somebody else has ideas, because I don’t